# How should my __lt__ code look like if I want .sort() to work on my list of classes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have created a carddeck and every player is assigned a hand. I would like the players to be able to arrange their hand with the lowest value first and then print out this hand. I would like to think this can be done with .sort() but atm I'm getting a message

```
TypeError: unorderable types: NumberedCard() < NumberedCard()
```

I got a tip from the net that if I defined how .sort() is to work through a correct `def __lt__(self, other):` then I wouldn't be having this problem. So help me programmers figure this one out. Every card is defined by value and suit.

My code looks like this:

```
import random

suitlist=["Hearts","Spades","Clubs","Diamonds"]

class NumberedCard():
    def __init__(self,value,suit):
        self.value=value
        self.suit=suit

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s of %s' %(self.value,suitlist[self.suit])

class JackCard():
    def __init__(self,suit):
        self.suit=suit
        self.value=11

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Jack of %s' %(suitlist[self.suit])

class QueenCard():
    def __init__(self,suit):
        self.suit=suit
        self.value=12

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Queen of %s' %(suitlist[self.suit])

class KingCard():
    def __init__(self,suit):
        self.suit=suit
        self.value=13

    def __str__(self):
        return 'King of %s' %(suitlist[self.suit])

class AceCard():
    def __init__(self,suit):
        self.suit=suit
        self.value=14
    def __str__(self):
        return 'Ace of %s' %(suitlist[self.suit])

class StandardDeck():
    """A class that creates a deck of 52 different cards, that also gives options to do matching operations with them"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.deck = []
        for suit in range(4):
            for value in range(2,11):
                card = NumberedCard(value,suit)
                self.deck.append(card)
            self.deck.append(JackCard(suit))
            self.deck.append(QueenCard(suit))
            self.deck.append(KingCard(suit))
            self.deck.append(AceCard(suit))
            #for k in range(52):
            #    print(self.deck[k])

    def shuffle(self):
        """Shake n' bake with the cards."""
        random.shuffle(self.deck)

    def take_card(self):                        
        return self.deck.pop()

    def deal_cards(self, hand,num):                
        for i in range(num):
            hand.add_card(self.take_card())

class Hand:
    """A class to do the usual poker things during the game. Ie pick up cards, drop cards etc."""
    def __init__(self):
       self.hand = []

    def __str__(self):
        Handen=""
        for card in self.hand:
            Handen+=str(card) + "\n"
        return Handen

    def add_card(self,card):
        self.hand.append(card)


    def sort_cards(self):
        self.hand.sort()


####Testing the program
deck=StandardDeck()
deck.shuffle()
hand=Hand()
hand.add_card(deck.take_card())
hand.add_card(deck.take_card())
print(hand)
hand.sort_cards()  # <---- This is the part not working
```

So how is it done and where should it be put?

Comment: You are using python3 not python 2

Comment: Uhh accidentally posted my temporary solution to Hand.sort_cards(). Just go ahead and skip whatever is written inside the """.

Comment: How about you just go ahead and edit the question?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham there you go. Want to blame on my tieredness :)
@ jonrsharpe First thought was that things couldn't be edited. But thanks, it's done now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to salvage this would be to create a `class Card` which would have a `value` and the `__lt__` or `__gt__` and a `__eq__` defined method. And then proliferate those method by having all the other cards inherit from that parent class.

The proposed methods could be as simple as just compairing values of `value` which is an `int` and python knows how to do it himself.

Something like this:

```
>>> class Card(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    def __lt__(self, other):
        if other.value > self.value:
            return True
        return False

>>> class Ace(Card):
    def __init__(self, value):
        super().__init__(value)

>>> class NumCard(Card):
    def __init(self, value):
        super().__init__(value)

>>> jack = Ace(12)
>>> n = NumCard(7)
>>> jack > n
True
>>> n > jack
False
```

Comment: It worked perfect! Thank you @ljetibo. Now I just have to study what super() actually does but I'll find it somewhere else. Have a nice evening!

Comment: @ChalmersStudent did you manage to get a good grip on class inheritance and `super`?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to sort the list in self.hand why not just use the key argument for sort to create a function to return the value to sort on?

```
self.hand.sort(key=lambda x: x.value)
```

[This link should provide some info on sorting techniques](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting)